# How to get CPU/RAM usage from differenet servers?

Tags: php, server, cpu-usage, ram

I wonder how I could show on one main page "Monitoring.php" a couple of different servers to get theire cpu/ram usage.

This is the current Code I'm using. But the thing is i only get the CPU/Ram usage of the current server, where the .php files are stored.

```
function get_server_cpu_usage(){

    $load = sys_getloadavg();
    return $load[0];

}


function get_server_memory_usage(){

    $free = shell_exec('free');
    $free = (string)trim($free);
    $free_arr = explode("\n", $free);
    $mem = explode(" ", $free_arr[1]);
    $mem = array_filter($mem);
    $mem = array_merge($mem);
    $memory_usage = $mem[2]/$mem[1]*100;

    return $memory_usage;
}


echo '<h4>Server Memory usage: ' . number_format(get_server_memory_usage(), 2) . '%</h4><div class="meter"><span style="width:' . get_server_memory_usage() . '%"></span></div><br>
<h4>Server CPU usage: '     . get_server_cpu_usage() . '% </h4><div class="meter"><span style="width:' . get_server_cpu_usage() . '%"></span></div>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a php script that stores the data into a common data storage 
   like `mysql`, `redis` etc.
2. Add the php script to cron job to do it in an interval, for that on each server run `crontab -e`, it will bring you an editor
   window    where; put the script interval logic.
3. modify `monitor.php` file to get contents from common database.

example:

**cron script**

```
  // do.php it runs in every server you have  
  $cpu_usage = get_server_cpu_usage();  
  $memory_usage = get_server_memory_usage();  
  // you can use hostname, ip name logic  
  $server_id = get_server_uniqid();   
  //logic to insert data  
  insert_monitor_data($server_id, $cpu_usage, $server_id);
```

**crontab file**

```
*/10 * * * * /path/to/do.php
```

the cron will run every 10 minutes in individual servers & store the data to a common data store.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use any 3rd party tools, which your script will access i would see this simple options

Running your script on every server, and store the information for each server in a shared MYSQL or Memcache instance.

Or you create a script like like showstatus.php on each server, which returns all required information in JSON. Then your actual monitoring server can collect the JSON from each server and process it.